# Using iconClassName to material-ui FloatingActionButton

Tags: material-ui, floating-action-button

How do I use the 'iconClassName' prop of FloatingActionButton to show an icon inside it? I know how to assign an icon this way:

```
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu'
...
<FloatingActionButton>
    <IconMenu />
</FloatingActionButton>
```

But that is not how I want to do it. According to the docs, I can use the 'iconClassName' prop to assign an icon.

I have included the link to material icons in the HTML file:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

But now, it doesn't matter how I try to assign the icon name, it doesn't show up. I tried these combinations using dashes:

```
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='menu' />
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='navigation-menu' />
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='material-icons-menu' />
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='material-icons-navigation-menu' />
```

Or with underscores:

```
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='navigation_menu' />
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='material_icons_menu' />
<FloatingActionButton iconClassName='material_icons_navigation_menu' />
```

None of them works. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred way is to use it like this:

```
<FloatingActionButton>
  <FontIcon className="material-icons">home</FontIcon>
</FloatingActionButton>
```

If iconClassName is defined FloatingActionButton renders a FontIcon inside it anyway. But it's only applying the classNames and not setting any ligatures. I'm not sure if this is a bug in material-ui.

https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have issues using it any other way, except for `iconClassName`, so I'm not sure what's the deal there. As you said, it might be a bug.